# Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, django, django-1.8, python-3.5, django-email

JUST tried to link an email address to the simple form and the error continued to occur which I couldn't fix yet. can you please help me to understand what does this error actually mean. and the possible way to get rid of it.

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'newsletter')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-        packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,   *callback_args,      **callback_kwargs)
File "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\src\newsletter\views.py" in contact
66.                 fail_silently=True)
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-  packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py" in send_mail
62.     return mail.send()
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py" in send
303.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in send_messages
100.             new_conn_created = self.open()
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py" in open
58.             self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 32\lib\smtplib.py" in __init__
251.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py" in connect
335.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py" in _get_socket
306.                                         self.source_address)
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py" in create_connection
689.     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Users\Lokesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 32\lib\socket.py" in getaddrinfo
728.     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

Exception Type: gaierror at /contact/
Exception Value: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: have you specified `EMAIL_BACKEND`, `EMAIL_HOST`, `EMAIL_PORT`, `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`, `EMAIL_USE_TLS` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: yes, properly specified... @Nhor

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced this same problem, and I was able to fix it by making sure that in my django `settings.py`, where my email setting snippet is that none of my email setting variable value should by any means carry a space as that will change your email endpoint.

> IN MY CASE OLD CODE(The error in this code is in EMAIL_HOST):

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com '
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your google gmail app generated password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

> FORMATED CODE, THE WORKING ONE:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your google gmail app generated password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I hope this works for you!